# Proving if $F^{-1} $ is function $\Rightarrow F^{-1}$ is $1-1$?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Let F be a function from set A to set B.

> If $F^{-1}$ is a function, then $F^{-1}$ is one to one.
>
> Prove: If $F: A \rightarrow B $ and $F^{-1}$ is a function, then F is one-to-one.

Proof:

Let $\left( g \circ f \right)(a_1) = (g \circ f)(a_2)$

$\Rightarrow g(f(a_1)) = g(f(a_2)).$

As g is one to one, $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$

As $f$ is one then $a_1= a_2$

Hence $g \circ f $ is one to one $∎$

Please critique my proof and verify if I am right or wrong.

Comment: what does the function g stand for?

Comment: You should also clarify what $F^{-1}$ is (if it failed to be a function, then what would it be?). You should also use the same notation in your proof as in the theorem (I assume $f$ is $F$ and $g$ is $F^{-1}$, but that shouldn't be an assumption the reader has to make).

Comment: I edited the question for better clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any $a_1, a_2 \in A$ such that $F(a_1) = F(a_2)$. We want to show that $a_1 = a_2$. Indeed, since $F^{-1}$ is a well-defined function, we know that it must map equal inputs to the same output. Thus, it follows that $F^{-1}(F(a_1)) = F^{-1}(F(a_2))$ so that $a_1 = a_2$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: Were you using the direct proof method for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The question as stated is a little confusing. I will assume that you are trying to prove the following:

> If $f : A \to B$ possesses an inverse, then that inverse is one-to-one.

The proof is as follows: Suppose $f^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}(y)$ for $x, y \in B$. Then $f(f^{-1}(x)) = f(f^{-1}(y))$, which is precisely the statement that $x=y$.

Comment: I knew what I wrote was wrong I just needed someone to verify it for me.

Comment: @ZachBlumenstein Note it is sufficient to show that if f is  invertible f is 1-1. But if you map two distinct points to one point, the inverse maps one point to two distinct points, is not a function.