# Why is finding all subsets of a set (power set) an exponential problem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, exponential-function, combinations

I know it's function of $2^n$ where $n$ is the number of elements in the original set. But what is so doubling (100% growth) about finding all subset of a set?

Usually for $2^n$ function we can represent it as a binary tree but I can't work my way to understand why it's exponential in this case. It's a property but I can't link it to usual methods of understanding $2^n$.

Comment: Fundamental counting principle iterated n times.

Comment: You either include or exclude the "newest" or "maximal" element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* represent the process of identifying all subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ as a binary tree. Here’s a rough sketch for $n=3$:

[image]

At the first stage we ask whether $1$ is in the subset; at the second whether $2$ is in the subset; and so on. Since the question always has $2$ possible answers, each level of the tree has twice as many nodes as the previous level, and after $n$ questions we have

$$1\cdot\underbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot\ldots\cdot 2}_{n\text{ doublings}}=2^n$$

nodes. Each subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is completely determined by the answers to these $n$ questions, and each string of *yes/no* answers completely determines a subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, so at the last level there is exactly one node for each subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Thus, $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ must have $2^n$ subsets.

Comment: this reminded me an analogy I once had but forgot somehow. It was to mimic binary system; consider given set as a your ascii character system consisting on n characters then you need 2^n bits to represent all combinations of subsets. but that was just analogy. thanks for the deeper fundamentals which applies to binary system as well.

Comment: @nir: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I_n = \{1, \dots, n\}$. The power set $P(I_n)$ is the disjoint union of $\{X\subset I_n:\, n\not\in X\}$ and $\{X\subset I_n:\, n\in X\}$. The maps $\alpha \to \alpha$ and $\alpha \to \alpha \cap I_{n-1}$ are bijections from these respective sets onto $P(I_{n-1})$, so $\#P(I_n) = \#2P(I_{n-1})$. The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

What follows is something I wrote a while back for a problem that appears in the beginning of Munkres' famed *Topology* text. I'm posting a picture because I'm too lazy to type it all out verbatim, but I imagine it may address what you are referencing.

*Note:* Begin at "*Inductive Argument 1*" for the part that explicitly addresses your question.

---

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It is sufficient that given any subset of $\{0,...,n-2\}$ (with $n-1$ elements), there are two ways to extend it to a subset of $\{0,....,n-1\}$ (with $n$ elements). But the extension either includes or excludes $n-1$, so we are done.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will help you. Or are you **still** [refusing](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869031/proving-if-f-1-is-function-rightarrow-f-1-is-1-1/1869037#comment3828952_1869037) to typeset your responses correctly? -1

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow The question is now typeset. Please remove your -1 as it is no longer pertinent to the post.